# Capture CLI input silently with Node (i.e. hide password input)

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, command-line-interface

I am making a CLI app that takes a user's password. I would not like the password to appear on the screen as they type. It should display a placeholder, or nothing at all. Such as:

```
$ node myapp.js
Please enter your email: myemail@myprovider.com
Please enter your password: ******
```

EDIT: I was using the `read` package before, but marking input as `silent: true` does not work with nodemon.

Comment: have a look at this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/prompt, it has exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the node packages, `read` or `prompt`. Keep in mind, **they don't work with nodemon**. They work, but the password will still be displayed when run with nodemon. This should only affect development since end users will run it with simply `node`.